# Parse/Split a string and upload it into the database

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to split/parse a string into several parts and then correctly upload it into the database.

I have a string like that :

```
String CARDS =
        "e \"Water\"\n" +
        "n \"John\"\n" +
        "p \"Big\"\n" +
        "e \"Fire\"\n";
```

I want to separate each line and have something like

```
 e
 "Water"
 n
 "John"
```

I managed to do it by with something like this :

```
      String delim = " \n\r\t,.;"; //insert here all delimitators
      StringTokenizer card = new StringTokenizer(CARDS,delim);
      while (card.hasMoreTokens()) {
          System.out.println(card.nextToken());
      }
```

I have created a small table called card which contains card_type and card_desc.
Where the card_type would be the first letter like e, n etc and then the card_desc would be Water , John etc.

I also have an insert method :

```
public void insert() throws SQLException {
    Connection con = ListPlayers.myCon.get();
    String query = "INSERT INTO deck (card_type,card_desc) VALUES (?,?);";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, card_type);
    ps.setString(2, card_desc);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.close();
}
```

I am just not sure how to succesfully divide the splited string into card type and desc and then upload it to the database.

Comment: You should avoid calling close manually. Instead place your PreparedStatement in a try-with statement which will guarantee a close in exception situations. 
 You also may need to close your connection assuming you are using a modern connection pool. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already done the hard part. Just replace the quotes (") from your description and call your method to insert the data.
Update your while loop.

```
while (card.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String card_type = card.nextToken();
    String card_desc = card.nextToken().replace("\"","");
    //you can call your insert method to insert the data
    // example insert(card_type,card_desc)
    System.out.println(card_type+"::"+card_desc);
}
```

I have added the print just to test.

Update your insert method to pass the parameters.